# Output current Phusion Passenger configuration values

Tags: nginx, passenger

Sometimes a man has a need to view some particular configuration value.
Let's say in nginx.conf I have a line like `passenger_max_pool_size 69;`.

So is there some way to output (to terminal) this value?

Imagine something like this:

> $ passenger-config-value passenger_max_pool_size
>   $ 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `passenger-status --show=xml`. It will show you the internal state as an XML dump, including memoized configuration options.